# @ character is not displayed in Watson Conversation Service response string

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

In working with IBM Watson Conversation Service (WCS) I want to print an email address in the response. The problem is that WCS is neglecting all the characters after @ symbol and the @ character itself.

I tried using `'` and `\` to escape it, but it didn't help much.

How can I print an email address in a response string?

Comment: How do you print it? How is the value passed into Watson Conversation?

Comment: I'm using the ask Watson chat present in right corner of the build environment

Comment: Using ` \ `  should work. Example `bob\@email.com`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the email address is passed into the Watson Conversation service as a context variable, then it can be returned (printed) as part of the response string. Assuming the variable is named "email" and its value is "henrik@example.com", the following would do as response:

```
Hello, your mail address is <? $email ?>
```

It would return:

```
Hello, your mail address is henrik@example.com
```

However, you need to be careful if you want to print out special characters such as `@`. [The reason is that it refers to entities. It is a shorthand](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/expression-language.html#accessing-and-evaluating-objects). In that case you need to escape that sign with `\`, e.g., `\@`. Here is a hardcoded response:

```
Please contact support at support\@example.com
```

Comment: You don't need `<? ?>`  if all you write is `$email`

Comment: That's correct, but I wanted to give the more generic syntax

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your question, but, if you want to return the mail address inside the conversation, you can add the `mail` address value inside the `context` variable [advanced response]:

```
{
  "context": {
    "mail": "mail@domain.com"
  },
  "output": {
    "text": {
      "values": [
        "Your mail address is $mail"
      ],
      "selection_policy": "sequential"
    }
  }
}
```

And use `$mail`[*method for access contexts variables*] for access this value and return in your conversation something like:

```
if bot recognizes yourCondition response "Your mail address is $mail
```

But, if you want to use some custom code for that, you can add the return from your Conversation message call, something like:

```
//add inside your call, like:
conversation.message(payload, function (err, data) {
    data.context.mail= "mail@domain.com";
    if (err) {
      return res.status(err.code || 500).json(err);
    }
    updateMessage(payload, data, req, res);

  });
});
```

And in your Watson Conversation Service, you can use this variable inside every response message with `$mail`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the same problem. I had faced it. and the solution is very pretty simple.

if you are using watson assistant UI try in response like,

```
youremail\@gmail.com
```

it will work,
if you are using watson assistant API to manipulate the dialog. 
you have to give

```
"youremail\\@gmail.com"
```

I don't know the reason for that. but, the solution seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to write a static email address, you might have to hack it. It seems like WCS assumes you know what you're doing if you add a (dummy) variable in the response.

ex: `Email addr@gmail.com!`

results in: `Email addr!` (text)

but: `Email addr@gmail.com! <? $x >`

results in: `Email addr@gmail.com!` (link)

the former is just the literal 'addr'

the latter is the link: ([addr@gmail.com](http://mailto:addr@gmail.com)) < a href="mailto:addr@gmail.com" class="WAC__Link WAC__Link-email" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" > addr@gmail.com < / a >