# IBM Watson Assistant: How do I include a hyperlink that is an anchor link as a response?

Tags: hyperlink, chatbot, ibm-watson

I want to use the chatbot to display a link to a specific location on a webpage using an anchor link, but the # sign seems to mess this up. Here is what I have right now,

You can see the clip mode in action here: Clip Mode

The chatbot changes the link to https://us.support.fl-ux.run-edge.com/scenes/false in the response.

Answer (score 0):

since `#` is a special token in Watson Assistant you will have to prefix it with `\`

here is more info: [@ character is not displayed in Watson Conversation Service response string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712519/character-is-not-displayed-in-watson-conversation-service-response-string)